# IllegalArgumentException of concurrent ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor for scheduleAtFixedRate

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot

I am running a test file for HotSpot, JDK8 on my Mac. I use IntelliJ IDEA to run this java program.

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2
Build #IC-171.4249.39, built on April 25, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-736-b16 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.12.5
```

---

I got an error when I set `frequency` in `Runner.java` file. For example, if I set 25,5 to substitute 50 in the following assignment, I will get errors. Why is that?

`int frequency = 50 * runSpecification.objectSize / runSpecification.allocationRatePerSecond; // 25 will fail and yield bug`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:565)
    at eu.plumbr.gc.Runner.run(Runner.java:30)
    at eu.plumbr.gc.Runner.main(Runner.java:21)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

---

```
.
└── main
    └── java
        └── eu
            └── plumbr
                └── gc
                    ├── Consumer.java
                    ├── Producer.java
                    ├── RunSpecification.java
                    └── Runner.java

5 directories, 4 files
```

#### Consumer.java

```
package eu.plumbr.gc;

import java.util.Deque;

public class Consumer implements Runnable{

  private Deque<byte[]> deque;

  public Consumer(Deque<byte[]> deque) {
    this.deque = deque;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    deque.poll();
  }
}
```

#### Producer.java

```
package eu.plumbr.gc;

import java.util.Deque;

public class Producer implements Runnable {

  private Deque<byte[]> deque;
  private int objectSize;

  public Producer(Deque<byte[]> deque, int objectSize) {
    this.deque = deque;
    this.objectSize = objectSize;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    deque.add(new byte[objectSize]);
  }
}
```

#### Runner.java

```
package eu.plumbr.gc;

import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Runner {

  private RunSpecification runSpecification;
  private ScheduledExecutorService executorService;

  public Runner(RunSpecification runSpecification, ScheduledExecutorService executorService) {
    this.runSpecification = runSpecification;
    this.executorService = executorService;
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Runner runner = new Runner(new RunSpecification(10 * 1024, 1024 * 500, 5), Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2));
    runner.run();
  }

  public void run() {
    ArrayDeque<byte[]> deque = new ArrayDeque<byte[]>();
    Producer producer = new Producer(deque, runSpecification.objectSize);
    Consumer consumer = new Consumer(deque);

    int frequency = 50 * runSpecification.objectSize / runSpecification.allocationRatePerSecond; // 25 will fail and yield bug
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(producer, 0, frequency, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(consumer, 1000 * runSpecification.ttl, frequency, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  }
}
```

#### RunSpecification.java

```
package eu.plumbr.gc;

public class RunSpecification {
  public int objectSize;
  public int allocationRatePerSecond;
  public int ttl;

  public RunSpecification(int objectSize, int allocationRatePerSecond, int ttl) {
    this.objectSize = objectSize;
    this.allocationRatePerSecond = allocationRatePerSecond;
    this.ttl = ttl;
  }
}
```

Reference:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Comment: [MCVE] this is a lot of code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the javadocs you will see

*IllegalArgumentException - if period less than or equal to zero*

Not knowing your exact input, but I would say that with

```
int frequency = 50 * runSpecification.objectSize / 
                      runSpecification.allocationRatePerSecond;
```

`frequency` is greater than 0, but with using 25 it is not

Remember that you are doing Integer division and this can be verified by

```
    int objectSize = 10240; 
    int allocationRatePerSecond = 512000;

    System.out.println(50 * objectSize / allocationRatePerSecond);
    System.out.println(25 * objectSize / allocationRatePerSecond);
```

**output**

```
1
0
```

Comment: runSpecification.objectSize = 10240;  runSpecification.allocationRatePerSecond = 512000;

Answer (score 0):

Based on the solution suggested by 'Scary Wombat', I have done the changes and got rid of the error. ie., *IllegalArgumentException - if period less than or equal to zero*

Initial code:

```
private ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, 0, 1, TimeUnit.valueOf(DAYS));
```

Corrected code:

```
private ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, 1, 1, TimeUnit.valueOf(DAYS));
```

Changed the second parameter from 0 to 1 and it worked!!